# Autofac - Class oriented scope

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dependency-injection, autofac

I am using autofac with .net core 3 currently. I dont know how to pass runtime variable which will be diffrent when `Root` is invoked from class `A` and diffrent when from `B`.

```
class A{Root root}
class B{Root root}

 
class Root
{
 Root()
 {
   if(resolvedForClassA) 
     DoSomethingForClassA();
   else
     DoSomethingForClassB();
 }
}
```

Yes, this condition must be done in the constructor.

Is it possible and if yes, could you give me some hint how to accomplish it?

Comment: I think you're looking for this https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html#selection-of-an-implementation-by-parameter-value

Comment: "Yes, this condition must be done in the constructor." And why is that? Doing anything non-trivial in injection constructors is [highly discouraged](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/).

Comment: When Root is initializing it is not decided where it is going to be used. Why you want to deal with A or B in Root's constructor?